# I have value in array i want print it in headerphp

Tags: php, arrays, header

I'm doing  a small project  about date hajiri and can't print value from array saved in RAM

```
header("Location: http://localhost/date.php?da=".$this->day);
```

please check line 28

```
<?php

class date {

    private $date ;
    public $filter ,$Steps ,$day;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/search?q=hijri+date&rlz=1C5CHFA_enSA864en864&oq=hajri&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.9448j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8');
        $this->filter = preg_match_all('/<div class="BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd">(.*?)(?=class="ZINbbc)/i',$this->date,$matches);
        $this->Steps = $matches[0][0];
        $this->Steps = substr($this->Steps,71 ,160);
        $this->Steps = explode(" ", $this->Steps);
    }

    public function ApiDate(){
      print_r($this->Steps);
       //$this->day = "s";
       $this->day =   utf8_encode($this->Steps[2]);


        echo $this->day;
        header("Location: http://localhost/date.php?da=".$this->day);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your date variable is private you have to use a getter and setter for this or else make date public which isn't recommended approach.

Comment: @NithinSuresh - OP is within the class so `private` is OK.

Comment: Are you sure `$this->day` is populated? That code within the constructor looks awfully suspicious. What happens if `$this->Steps` is not populated with that you expect? Change the code in the constructor to make it more robust. Maybe set a flag that ApiDate can check to see if the data is ready.

Comment: Make sure the server did not already returned some html before your header assignment. Otherwise take a look at the following: [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) buffer your response first.